# System Comments Button

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi does anyone know where I can get the comments button used in WP7 from? (the one you see in pictures hub and peoples "What's New" pages)

I've seen it used in 4th & Mayor and Rowi so wondered if this was a system resource or something

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that button is a custom control, not something available out of the box. Having said that, it should be quite easy to recreate. It looks liks it's simply a button with a small `path` for the little extension at the bottom. The standard icons available can be found in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.0\Icons

(assuming default installation directory)